# How can I pass an msbuild condition from the command line?

Tags: msbuild, command-line-arguments, conditional-statements

I have a target as part of my build that I wish to skip upon evaluation of some command line check:

```
<Target Name="RunSomeDependencyVerification" Condition="!Exists('$(SkipVerification)')">
....
```

I want to pass the skip verification in from the console such that:

```
msbuild mybuild.dev.proj /p:SkipVerification
```

My build script complains that the "SkipVerification" property is not defined. I've found the documentation for `<PropertyGroup />` but it seems like that not only defines the property, but sets the value too, which isn't what I'm after.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Define your property with a default value in your original msbuild file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SkipVerification Condition="'$(SkipVerification)'==''">False</SkipVerification>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Your use of "Exists" check is off I think.. (aka, nicely saying: it is the wrong syntax-sugar for what you are trying to do.)
I think you want to check the VALUE of your property.  As seen below: (no "Exists" used :) )

```
<Target Name="RunSomeDependencyVerification" Condition="'$(SkipVerification)'=='True'">
```

Then this.

```
/p:Configuration=Debug;SkipVerification=True
```

Please note:

Configuration=Debug; is **not** a part of what you need, I just wanted to show how to specify more than 1 property in the command line. (that you use a ";" delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

Msbuild says `SkipVerification` is not defined because it isn't: `Exists` is for files or directories, not for properties. Try this instead:

```
msbuild mybuild.dev.proj /p:SkipVerification=true
```

And then check on the value:

```
<Target Name="RunSomeDependencyVerification"
        Condition="'$(SkipVerification)'!='true')">
```